# VLOOKUP - Find lookup value may be seperated by comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two lists, where I need to see if values from the 1st list is also present in the 2nd list. However, due to the way my system is formatted, some values from the 1st list contains multiple values, that needs to be looked up.

If just one of the values is present in the 2nd list, it should print that value.

**1st list values:**

```
COLUMN A:
C00276129, CDK1029191
CAE031070
CAU029379
```

**2nd list values:**

```
COLUMN B:
CDK1029191
CAE031070
CUS0000000
CUS0000002
```

As you can see, in list one, some of the values may be printed out on the same row, but seperated by comma.

I am trying to get `VLOOKUP` to search for both values in list 1 and compare to the entire list 2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1 & "*";B:B;1;FALSE);"Value not present")
```

However, above just returns "Value not present", even though the value on the first row is indeed present in list 2.

Comment: `"*" & A1 & "*"`

Comment: how many instances could be in one row? just 2?

Comment: Yes a maximum of two

Comment: @ScottCraner Doesn't work by adding "*" before A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this "Clumsy" formula to return just value that was found in case 2 values are in same row. `=TRIM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2,1)-1),B:B,1,FALSE),"")&" "&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(",",A2,1)-1),B:B,1,FALSE),"")&" "&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,B:B,1,FALSE),""))`

[image]